# Increment DateTime Variable

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to create a loop where my date increments by 1 month while it's in the for loop. Currently It's only displaying today's date. And is not incrementing. I want to change the display date to selected display date instead of today/default

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
{

    DateTime initialdate = InitialDate.DisplayDate;
    InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);
    initialdate = InitialDate.DisplayDate;

}
```

I didn't show any of the initialdate being used because I don't think it's necessary.

InitialDate is a DateTimePicker
Initialization of the Datepicker
    `<DatePicker x:Name="InitialDate"></DatePicker>`

Comment: DateTime values are immutable. The operation will return a new DateTime value that you need to assign it to a new DatTime type variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem :** You need to assign the return value of the `InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1)`.

From MSDN: [DateTime.AddMonths()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Returns** a new DateTime that adds the specified number of months to the
>   value of this instance.

Replace This:

```
InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);
```

With This:

```
InitialDate.DisplayDate = InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Comment: Perfect answer! May I ask how I fix the default date issue. It's displaying todays date rather than selectedDate

Comment: Do you think instead of display Date, It needs to be selected date to fix it?

Comment: @user3276954: yes exactly. try that.

Answer (score 9):

[`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't change the value you call it on - it returns a *new* value. This is true of *all* the `DateTime` methods. There's nothing which changes the value in place, which is a good job as it's a value type and changes would be lost anyway if they were made to a copy of the variable (e.g. due to being called on the value returned by a property).

You want:

```
InitialDate.DisplayDate = InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Assuming you use `initialdate` in the rest of the body of the loop, it would be clearer if you just declared it *after* the increment:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
{
    InitialDate.DisplayDate = InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);
    DateTime initialDate = InitialDate.DisplayDate;
    // Use initialDate here
}
```

(I've renamed the variable to have a capital `D` for the sake of convention.)

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
DateTime initialdate = InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonth(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem stems from the fact that `InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);` returns a new `DateTime` rather than modifying the instance it's being called on. You do nothing with the return value emitted by that call. Instead you want;

```
InitialDate.DisplayDate = InitialDate.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Just FYI you will see this a lot in C#. I would say more often than not, methods that would change the values of an object return a new instance rather than mutating the instance they're called on.